# R smoothing curve function and potential coordinates

Tags: r

Using the below code:

> table <- df_base %>% group_by(spread_favorite) %>% summarise(wins =
> sum(underdog_win), games = n(), pct = wins / games)

I get a table like (just a snippet, full table has over 50 rows):

| spread_favorite | wins | games | pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -5.0 | 98 | 318 | .308 |
| -4.5 | 116 | 347 | .334 |
| -4.0 | 213 | 570 | .374 |

I created a point plot, would love to paste in the image but not enough reputation points yet.

> plot <- ggplot(table, aes(x=spread_favorite, y=pct,size=games)) +
> geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x*100,
> "%")) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 13))

It has an upwards curve that would benefit from being represented as a smoothed curve line instead of individual points.  Would loess be the best function for this, or is there a better function to use?  I tried it but didn't have any success with it.

Additionally, would there be a function that creates the coordinates of the curve, so I could get a table that say -5.0 comes to .300 on the curve, instead of the .308 in the table?

Answer (score 1):

You only have 3 points in your data set, so there are infinitely many smooth curves that could fit perfectly. For example, a second-order polynomial fit looks very nice:

```r
ggplot(table, aes(x = spread_favorite, y = pct)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = games)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), se = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x*100, "%")) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 13))
```

[image]

To get the predictions along this line, just run `predict` on the appropriate model for your data:

```r
model <- lm(pct ~ poly(spread_favorite, 2), table)

df <- data.frame(spread_favorite = seq(-5, -4, 0.1))

df$pct <- predict(model, df)

df
#>    spread_favorite     pct
#> 1             -5.0 0.30800
#> 2             -4.9 0.31208
#> 3             -4.8 0.31672
#> 4             -4.7 0.32192
#> 5             -4.6 0.32768
#> 6             -4.5 0.33400
#> 7             -4.4 0.34088
#> 8             -4.3 0.34832
#> 9             -4.2 0.35632
#> 10            -4.1 0.36488
#> 11            -4.0 0.37400
```

This method should still work if you have lots of messy data points, as long as they follow a similar shape.

Comment: Sorry, I should have noted that the table above was just a subset of the entire table, the full table has about 50 rows.  I can try this out, would a different method work better for more points?  Appreciate you answering so quickly.

Comment: This should still work @Abartel, though it depends on your data. You can edit your question to include the output of `dput(table)`